I'm creating a token account but something always goes wrong
pub fn create_and_initialize_token_account(accounts: &[AccountInfo]) -> Result<(), ProgramError> {
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let owner_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let token_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let mint_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let system_program_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let rent_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?; // 租金账户
    let system_program = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?; // 租金账户

    // 获取租金信息
    let rent = &Rent::from_account_info(rent_account)?;

    // 计算创建代币账户所需的 lamports
    let lamports_needed = rent.minimum_balance(size_of::<TokenAccount>());
    // 创建代币账户
    let create_account_ix = system_instruction::create_account(
        token_account.key,
        owner_account.key,
        lamports_needed,
        size_of::<TokenAccount>() as u64,
        &spl_token::id(),
    );
    // 调用创建账户指令
    invoke(
        &create_account_ix,
        &[owner_account.clone(), system_program.clone()],
    )?;

    // 初始化代币账户

    let initialize_ix = token_instruction::initialize_account(
        &spl_token::id(),
        token_account.key,
        mint_account.key,
        owner_account.key,
    )?;

    invoke(
        &initialize_ix,
        &[
            token_account.clone(),
            mint_account.clone(),
            owner_account.clone(),
        ],
    )?;

    Ok(())
}

This is my code, I use it to create a token account but I always get an error


My guess would be to check whether you are passing in the mint account as a signer
Or perhaps you missed indicating that the owner_account, token_account and mint_account were mutable.
If you are manually doing this without an IDL and using a TransactionInstruction check whether you have everything in order under the keys field
const transferInstruction = new TransactionInstruction({
  keys: [
    { pubkey: owner, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
    { pubkey: mint, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
    { pubkey: tokenAccount, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
  ],
  programId: ,
  data: instructionData,
});

